# asynctask sqlite doesnt update

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I am making a register screen for my project. After register data is sent to web database I want the app also update local sqlite database so that the next time user opens the app, he/she doesn't need to do the same operations if the register is successfull. My app is updating the web database with no problem but when I try to do sqlite update with a second asynctask it doesn't update sqlite, what am I missing? :(

Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    final EditText vmail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText vpassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText vnickname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);




    Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mail=vmail.getText().toString();
            password=vpassword.getText().toString();
            mynickname=vnickname.getText().toString();
            new AsyncTaskClass().execute();
        }
    });
}
class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String reverseString =null;

        try
        {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail",mail));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mynickname",mynickname));
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("wwwmysite.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler); 
            reverseString = response;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return reverseString;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String reverseString) {
         if (reverseString.contains("success")){
             new AsyncTaskClass2().execute();                
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
class AsyncTaskClass2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String reverseString =null;
        try
        {
            KayitEkle(Array.get(nameValuePairs, 0).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 1).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 2).toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return reverseString;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String reverseString) {
        startActivity(new Intent(registergame.this, (mygamescreen.class)));
    }
}
 private void KayitEkle(String nick, String mail, String password){       
     SQLiteDatabase db = users.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues veriler = new ContentValues();
     veriler.put("nick", nick);
     veriler.put("mail",mail);
     veriler.put("password",password);
     db.insertOrThrow("ogrenciisim", null, veriler);
 }
```

}

Comment: What is the result of 1st AsyncTask? Is it "success"? Is your 2nd AsyncTask called?

Comment: it goes up to this command startActivity(new Intent(registergame.this, (mygamescreen.class)));

Comment: it gives error here; KayitEkle(Array.get(nameValuePairs, 0).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 1).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 2).toString()); saying that array is null at logcat how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Put a debugger to see if it is actually calling AsyncTaskClass2 doInBackground() method. If it does, then check the value returned by method insertOrThrow(). If return value is -1 then you need to check for that. This [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) will give you some insight

Comment: i found out that it gives error here;  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String reverseString =null;
        try
        {
            KayitEkle(Array.get(nameValuePairs, 0).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 1).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 2).toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        return reverseString;
    }
it says Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: array == null at logcat

Comment: If you see an exception, check why it is throwing it. Also if you inserted value based on Primary Key field in DB, it won't insert it again. Try reading from DB to see if value has been inserted before. I hope it helps. If my answer helped you figuring out problem, please upvote or mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: i changed to KayitEkle(nameValuePairs.get(0).getValue(),nameValuePairs.get(1).getValue(),nameValuePairs.get(2).getValue()); but it gives nullpointerexception :( i didnt understand what is wrong with the array

Answer (score 0):

You declared your nameValuePairs-variable only in your doInBackground-Method of your 1st AsyncTask:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

You could simply solve it, if you use your class-attribute nameValuePairs:

```
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

But as a general aspect, I do not see any cause why you should use a 2nd AsyncTask. Why don't you call the method

```
KayitEkle(Array.get(nameValuePairs, 0).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 1).toString(),Array.get(nameValuePairs, 2).toString());
```

in the doInBackground-Method of your 1st AsyncTask?